Does firmware on AirPods get updated when connected to an Apple TV?
I understand that Apple automatically updates the firmware for AirPods while charging when connected to an iPhone.
I have some AirPods used only with Apple TV. Will those get updated as well? Or should I occasionally connect the AirPods to my iPhone (and leave charging)?
Apple published the page About firmware updates for AirPods. That page lists current firmware version numbers. As for updating, it says:

Firmware updates are delivered automatically while your AirPods are charging and in Bluetooth range of your iPhone, iPad, or Mac that's connected to Wi-Fi.

That document omits any mention of Apple TV. So I would conclude that Apple TV does not update firmware, but I thought I would ask for confirmation here.

The document doesn't say that the AirPods have to be connected to an iPhone, iPad, or Mac; just that they have to be in Bluetooth range while charging. They pair automatically with all devices signed in to the same Apple Account, so I think this means you don't have to use them with your phone to get the update.

No, Apple TV is not listed as a valid firmware update source. Use your Mac, phone or pad.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/106340

Apple is very clear in making their documentation so an omission like this is nearly always intentional, but you could check since many devices just got an update to see if there is undocumented behavior.
